# precise timing with rosbag or an alternative

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The beginner's [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data) reads, that `rosbag` may be not precise when it comes to the timing. Some tasks I face are not Lyapunov stable, so precise data playback is necessary.

1. Could `rosbag` be precise with the usage of advanced technical hacks? E.g. RAM-disk as a bag file destination and dedicated CPU core for recording/playing. Are there any ROS directives/modes for precise timing?
2. Are there alternative means of recording and playing messages and requests/responses with precise timing (95% <1ms)? Unfortunately, some non-trivial data like camera output might be involved.

For simplicity let's assume we work with a single machine to avoid network latency issues.

ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04.05 x64.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313641/precise-timing-with-rosbag-or-an-alternative/) by [volume_8091](https://answers.ros.org/users/39641/volume_8091/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a solution where you can playback a bag file with perfectly accurate 'simulated' time, but not real time. The [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) provides the tools to make a node which can scan a read messages out of a bag file in any order or at any time. Using this package you can make a node which can read out and process the data with the exact time-stamps in the bag file, regardless of the actual real time taken to do the processing.

Hope this help.s

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a different answer for you :)

99% of the people use rosbag from the command line.
This means that your message is:

- Serialized on the publisher side.
- Sent it by TCP
- The rosbag recorder receive the  message,
- Message is    stored.

Very few people realize that instead of publishing it, you write the message inside your C++ application, avoiding the latency of point 2) and 3)

The only problem is that you have a single file per process, but you can merge this files later with a script...

Take a look to the C++ API or rosbag_storage https://docs.ros.org/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2019-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1